# Celery lost message when RabbitMQ stops

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I'm using a simple app to verify the problem that I have.

My task `add` append some string to a text file.

When RabbitMQ is running, I achieve this appending from an ipython shell executing `send_task('add', ('my message',))`.

Then I manually stops RabbitMQ and execute `send_task('add', ('a new message',))` in the same ipython session. This execution occurs without trwhoing any exception.

The **'a new messasage'** never been enqueued and not noticed about this.
In the subsequent send_task calls, an `OperationalError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer` is raised, that I properly handling with `try/except`.

How can I avoid this "first message" lost when Rabbit goes offline?

Thanks in advance.

Here a Video showing this issue in Action!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WmAYBkVJk7Q

**tasks.py**

```py
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://dev:dev@127.0.0.1/')

@app.task
def add(algo):
    print('Writing "{}" to file'.format(algo))
    open('/tmp/pepe.txt', 'a').write('{}\n'.format(algo))
```

**ipython shell** (just after stopping rabbitmq)

```py
In [1]: from celery import Celery

In [2]: cel = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://dev:dev@127.0.0.1/')

In [3]: cel.send_task('tasks.add', ('my message 23',))
Out[3]: <AsyncResult: a2167d23-3190-480b-bdb0-96dd1c98b08c>
```

Comment: In your case RabbitMQ is a message broker (storage), and Celery is an asynchronous task queue/job queue. So, if you stop broker (for example, by shutting down it), Celery will lost message you have put right after stop operation. Maybe I didn't understand your question correctly and you mean "RabbitMQ lost my unread message" (you have put it to the broker and than stop service). In this case you should read about acknowledgement (https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html)

Comment: @VictorPerov I create a Celery instance and publish one task: Fine!; Then I stop gracefully RabbitMQ; Then, using the created Celery instance, I publish a new task: Fail! Celery does not raise any exception, the broker is offline and the message is lost.
The, with the same Celery instance, I publish the 3rd task: Fine! An OperationError is raised!

That is clear? Sorry and thanks

Comment: @VictorPerov I recorded a video, that is better than my english: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WmAYBkVJk7Q

Comment: Oh, now I got it. Thanks for clarify. Perhaps problem lies in the "asynchronious" side of Celery. Your first task (right after stopping AMQP) fails because of connection timeout - celery response is ok because of service has pushed task and error is handled in other ("thread") callback. Than, when callback was received problems with connection, celery marks  connection as problematic and raise error. But it's just a my opinion. I'm not sure about python, but in the C and PHP I can check connection status.